# Raw emotions, was my question that unreasonable?

Tags: discussion

It is Friday. I wanted to ask this question a while ago. May be I will just say it now.

**I asked** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158721/sql-not-like-not-working **and answered it myself thinking that such question did not exist** (I searched first) and posted my own answer (by that time I had found what was wrong and it did eat up an hour of mine) thinking it may help someone. Initially it was received well but then **it was bombarded with down votes. My answer itself was downvoted and ultimately deleted**. As if I had touched raw emotions? I wasn't expecting this at all. All I thought ok question is appropriately answered or may be someone can answer it better and they will just move on, but people did not. They were stuck here. I am still getting downvotes on this question, got 1 today, got 2 last week. It seems there is no end to it.

Now this question can easily be deleted by a moderator or a couple of high reps user but it was never deleted and it continuously gets downvotes. Can someone put me in the right direction, did I really do something that wrong that people can't get over it? Were there raw emotions involved?

**Can we bring some type of closure to it so that it does not offend any other people? May be the question can be deleted? I apologize if hurt anyone.**

*Note: I am not asking for upvotes or downvotes, just wanted to raise this issue, related to raw emotions.*

> [image: screen shot]

Comment: Just FYI, linking to a question on meta will draw the attention of users; if it's a bad question, this often will lead to downvotes on that question.  I'm not saying you shouldn't ask, but a new influx of downvotes on that question is one possible side effect of asking.  Also note that a few downvotes are not the end of the world.  Don't take it as a slap to the face, because that's not their intent.  You've already realized your mistake and admitted to it, which is good; now you can just move on and not worry about the downvotes.

Comment: @Servy, this is ok. I wanted to know about raw emotions. How are they triggered and can it be unreasonably triggered?

Comment: You assume that a downvote is an emotional reaction. It usually isn't.  Don't take it so personally.  It's only indicating that it's a poor quality question.

Comment: One possible problem is that you couched the question in terms of SQL LIKE having a bug or problem ('not working'), when in fact the problem was in your poor understanding of boolean logic. You should avoid pointing the finger, it raises hackles.  Perhaps 'unexpected result from compound SQL LIKE statement' would have been better.

Comment: FYI, I don't normally delete questions that I close as a duplicate since part of the purpose there is to provide a link to the duplicate.  If someone searches for the terms in your answer, we want them to get to that dupe, not just return no results.

Comment: If you want to know about raw emotions, ask a psychologist.

Comment: @Servy I think the up/down vote is not so strongly followed here. If it touches your emotion then you up/down vote. There are questions here that have thousands of views and very helpful/clean/clear but only have 2 or 3 upvotes.

Comment: @Dave Most of those highly popularized questions are linked on lots of external sites and the views are from anonymous users without accounts; they simply didn't feel strongly enough to want to create a new account just to be able to vote.  Most questions don't get linked externally, are viewed primarily by people that have SO accounts (at least at first, until people start finding it on Google later) and the percentage of views/votes will be quite a lot higher.  In any case, a high view/vote ratio doesn't prove that people only vote because of a strong *emotional* reaction.

Comment: @Servy people do. [check this question on workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/is-it-rude-to-leave-an-interview-early-if-you-have-already-made-your-decision). It touched emotions, got 180+ votes in a week. Or was it really that good of a question that we face every day?

Comment: @Dave What's you basis for assuming that just because a question received 180+ votes in a week that it is because of a strong emotional reaction?  What is your basis from assuming that the motivation for voting on some other linked question is similar to the motivation for people voting on your question?  You're making lots of assumptions and not actually backing them up with anything.  Are there comments on your post that would indicate a strong emotional reaction?  (all of the comment I see indicate the opposite).

Comment: @Servy people generaly vote correct based on how good/bad a question is. I am not saying that. What I am saying is emotions triggers it a lot faster and may be sometime unreasonable. There are many many *basic* questions asked here every day. No one is stuck with them and downvates it every day? Or they do? Why were ppl stuck with my question? Downvoting continued for 2 months?

Comment: @Dave Do you go around looking at lots of old poorly asked questions?  I know I see quite a few that do indeed get downvoted quite a bit, and over the course of an extended period of time.  Your assumption that you are unique in this regard is incorrect.  Several people have provided reasons why your question was more likely to have been downvoted, and none of them involve people thinking you're a terrible person and wishing to just punish you "just because".

Comment: @Servy how do you explain, my answer to the question itself was deleted without any reasonable comments?

Comment: @Dave Your answer was deleted before I saw the question (meaning it must have been deleted before this meta post, because I noticed this question right when you posted it).  I am basing my comments entirely on the question and comments on the question.

Comment: @Servy added jpg just so you see everything including myanswer that was deleted by community :)

Comment: @Dave Okay, and what aspect of that do you feel indicates a strong emotional reaction?  What comments indicate that they didn't downvote/delete based on the SO guidelines and on the merits of the answer?

Comment: @Servy *strong* reaction to my question, not letting it go and forget, being stuck with it, downvoting without comments, not deleting the question itself, deleting my answer with our any comments or SO guidlines. That's all I can say.

Comment: @Dave It's not like the same person saved the question and kept coming back to it.  Each person can only vote once.  The votes coming in later were from people finding the question for the first time and choosing to downvote, either because they found it when searching for related content, from a review queue, because someone posted/edited content that bumped it, etc.  Downvoting without comments doesn't indicate a strong emotional reaction.  There is no correlation between those activities.  The same applies for not commenting for the delete votes.

Comment: @Servy well good to know you do not support the emotion reason theory. I will stick to your view and think I asked a really bad question and my answer was totally flawed. Therefore it was deleted. Thanks

Comment: @Dave "*I think the up/down vote is not so strongly followed here. If it touches your emotion then you up/down vote.*" And now I can't downvote you. Your arrogant presumption of telling me why I do and do not downvote made me angry and want to downvote you. But then I would be downvoting you for the exact reason you state. So I can't downvote you at all. So instead, I'll vote to close as not constructive.

Comment: I have not got a reasonable answer here. My question was basic, ok, how many basic questions get -10 vote? How many answers get deleted here? the whole pointing game comes at me once again *why I asked* this question, noting said *why* it was severely down voted (because there are other bad questions as well, was this the only one bad?), nothing explained *why* my own answer was downvoted and deleted. To me this aims at raw emotions, but perhaps I am wrong. Thanks every one taking the time to address it.

Comment: your own answer doesn't make any sense, because as I said in my answer, the entire set would be expected based on the query you wrote. Based on the answers, the one that would be best for this question is indeed Aaron Bertrand's since he explains what your query does. Since nobody knows what was really intended, the answer you wrote is pointless.

Comment: @tehdoommarine again you are not explaining how many answers are deleted every day on SO. There are 4 millions of them. You guys are stuck, my question was not good, my answer was not good. Got that. Why was it deleted? Is it normal poor answers are deleted on SO by community?

Comment: @Dave - not just by the community, but also by those who have written the poor answers.

Comment: can't post questions here any more :(

Answer (score 20):

I went ahead and deleted it for you.  I think all the downvotes were due to the fact that you really didn't need to ask the question to begin with.  If you had *still been stuck* when you posted the question I doubt you would have gotten such a negative response.  But in cases where you realize you're just making a silly mistake like mentally miscalculating the result of an OR, it's probably not going to be helpful to future visitors to the site, so probably not worth posting.

Comment: now when I solve such a problem, I post it on my blog. So it will probably never happen again.

Answer (score 6):

> Can someone put me in the right direction, did I really do something that wrong that people can't get over it? Were there raw emotions involved?

The only "raw emotions" that seem to be involved here are *yours*. You act like every downvote you get is a personal slap in your face. It's *just two rep*.

Suck it up.

You asked a question that is widely considered to be unresearched and therefore perfectly downvote-able. Getting downvotes for asking a bad question is *how the site works*. You can disagree with the community assessment of your question. But it's their right to decide what is and is not a good question. And your's seems superficial, no matter how long it took you to fix it.

Comment: `s/seems superficial/is superficial/`

Comment: How do you explain my answer being deleted?

Comment: @Dave - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146285/164207

Comment: @Nicol - Did you mean to say "widely considered to be **researched**"?

Comment: @jmort253: No, I meant "unresearched". As in "didn't put any research effort into it."

Comment: @NicolBolas - Oh, I see. Got it now! :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the sql provided, those ARE the expected results. NOT LIKE A% OR NOT LIKE C% negate each other, beginning with A will meet the NOT LIKE C% and vice-versa. The fact that you said the entire set was unexpected when based on the code provided that was the expected results will confuse people, which results in a bad question.

Comment: is it common bad questions gets -10 votes here?  I haven't come across many.

Comment: in meta, downvotes are way more common.

Comment: No, I mean on main where I got -14, not here :)

Comment: less common, but there are quite a few negatively voted questions. many of them, just like that one, end up deleted.

Comment: Apparently they are not that common, out of 3 millions questions here my question was among top 100 downvoted question. [check this link for top 100 downvotes](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/79141). [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8539212/do-we-really-need-volatile-keyword-in-c) is rated among top 100 downvoted but has a score of negative -7.

Comment: btw I found [this question with -17 score](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263219/why-is-d-undefined) that beat my question

Comment: there was a question about how to send 100,000 emails weekly with 175 downvotes. that's enough to bring my SO rep from 331 to 1. it was deleted, though.